# Spring jpa transaction business to Dao

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

**business layer:**

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
   public void createOrUpdateAppPing(String s) {

      servicePingDao.createOrUpdateAppPing(s);
   }
}
```

**Dao layer**

```
public   void createOrUpdateAppPing(String sc) {
      EntityManager  entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();    
          pingScService(sc,entityManager);
          if(ifHasPingScConfig(sc,entityManager)) {
             updateScConfig(sc,entityManager);
          } else {
             createScConfig(sc,entityManager);      }
         entityManager.close();    
   }
```

here :
** pingScService has select query
** updateScConfig  - update query
 ** createScConfig-insert

```
 config service-datasorce.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xmlns:osgix="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium.xsd     
       ">

       <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="smx4" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="jpaAdapter"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="com.luthresearch.savvyconnect.model.PostgreSQLDialectUuid" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">       
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver.class}" />        
            <property name="url"             value="${database.savvyconnect.url}" />
            <property name="username"        value="${database.savvyconnect.username}" />
            <property name="password"        value="${database.savvyconnect.password}" />

    </bean>



        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

  </bean>


  IN service.xml


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="service"
        class="com.services.impl.SServicempl" autowire="byName">

    </bean>
            <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
  </beans>
```

Now i want to add transaction support at service layer ...How i can do this.

I tried adding `@Transaction` annotation but I am getting

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Comment: Did you declare a transaction manager in the Spring config files?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It's very exhaustive and has examples. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Comment: <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    
  </bean>

Comment: You also need <tx:annotation-driven /> if you want to use @Transactional

Comment: that is also i have added :(..but does not work.

Comment: How do you get an instance of the ServiceImpl class? You don't do new ServiceImpl(), do you?

Comment: I call the serviceImpl form webservice  and serviceImpl object get created using spring

Comment: <bean id="service"
  class="services.ServiceImpl" autowire="byName">

Comment: I assume you're putting @Transactional on the interface as well and not directly on the method in ServiceImpl?

Comment: I am putting on ServiceImpl function public void getCalculateData()

Comment: I did not put on interface ..Do i have to do that

Comment: You most likely need it on the interface method signature (for a variety of reasons.)  (For the same reasons, it's unlikely to do you any good on the actual implementation in ServiceImpl.)

Comment: you also need to add aopallance.jar and aspectj libraries to classpath.

Comment: @BobG: you're wrong: Read the documentation (I gave the link in a previous comment). It says: "Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces"

Comment: @JB Nizet: Durr, you're right.  I had been talking about Spring Security all day, and THOSE annotations are recommended on the interface declarations.  My bad!  So the inverse is true: Transactional annotations on ServiceImpl methods and not on the interface declarations.

Comment: @Chandra: please post the relevent parts of the two classes and interfaces, as well as the spring configuration.

Comment: I am not able to post code as comment ...:(

Comment: Please just edit your question if you want to post code examples.